# Removing reflection warning for .clone

Tags: java, reflection, clojure

How do I remove the reflection warning from this Clojure code that is attempting to call a Java clone method:

```
(defn clone-foo [m]
  (.clone m))
=> Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_PATH:2 - reference to field clone can't be resolved.
```

Surely if m is any instance of `java.lang.Object` it must have the `clone` method?

Is it something to do with `clone` being protected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can't call the `clone()` on an arbitrary `Object`.  And, since the `clone()` method is not exposed by `Cloneable`, cloning things in a "generic" fashion is somewhat difficult.  This is one of those leftover bits from the early days of java which is too late to change at this point.  If you control all the objects you need to clone, you could create your own `ReallyCloneable` interface which exposes the `clone()` method, or you could play your own tricks with reflection.

Comment: Thanks. Presumably with default interface methods in Java 8 they will fix this and add clone() to Cloneable?

Comment: @mikera - heh, that same thought occurred to me as well, however i don't think that will help.  i think you could add clone() to Cloneable already without a problem since Object has a clone() method.  there must be another reason why it hasn't been done.